# Solve for x in $a = x^b$ (mod n)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I would like to solve for $x$ in $a = x^b\ (mod\ n)$ given $a$, $b$, $n$. How might I go about doing this?

Comment: That answer primarily covers square roots, it doesn't seem to well cover a generalized case where b is some arbitrary integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general there is no such method.

Are the numbers small enough to brute force? Can you factor $n$?

Comment: In the specific case I'm working (bit of a tricky personal cryptanalysis brain teaser) n is known to be the product of primes p and q (n is semi-prime), and n is sufficiently large to make brute force unfeasible.
b is quite small, however (in my particular case, 5, but I was trying to come up with a more general picture).

Comment: Do you know $p$ and $q$?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: So you are basically trying to undo RSA?